Script-src in CSP breaks Wordpress site
Our typical approach with security headers with all our Wordpress sites is to use the Security Headers plugin, which allows for modification to CSP (or other headers, as needed).
A security team of one of our clients has highlight that 'script-src' has no value and it needs to have one.
Guidance to do this on Wordpress, usually, is to add 'unsafe-inline', but while this will get rid of their error message, it kills the CSP. That seems silly to me.  In fact, this security company has provided a CSP they approve of, which has 'self', then whitelisted domains, and then also has 'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval' in them, which I think makes the whole thing quite pointless, does it not?
However, adding 'self' and then attempting to whitelist domains or add hashes (I retrieved them for Google Inspect tool on the front end) just seems to annihilate site functionality.
Even if the front end looks mostly fine, the admin area just couldn't function with that CSP in place, because scripts got blocked.
It seems to me that a script-src value is only going to break the site.  I can't possibly whitelist everything in a Wordpress website with a whole bunch of plugins.
I have no clue about the nonce option, but that doesn't seem like that would work either.
Initially, I thought I'd see if 'self' works, but this busted up the site.
I then found some domains to highlight (from Inspect tool) and added these.
upgrade-insecure-requests; script-src 'self' www.google-analytics.com ajax.googleapis.com

This still created blocked issues in front end, so I found all highlighted items and took the hash codes that Google Inspect tool offered.
upgrade-insecure-requests; script-src 'self' www.google-analytics.com ajax.googleapis.com 'sha256-X4Lw680O3vHDfcugCTXZC2XBjSsINPznUu/llg5TLeM=' 'sha256-9/X26c8A4hhDm5l8PmjNQ136l7rnx1Gn9xXs2z3dup8=' 'sha256-rjfSUjIA2A20p4lATAefLLG7Fy7VJssnkJ+SnJ2TXNo=' 'sha256-8CDrIHh6tB5AzNP78jzvxel49L6+yhTXv9yQl1quuoM=' 'sha256-7Z3UDEMxIvz4kUrStwbwTbyERD+xdMIfqGziBlViKec=' 'sha256-RWn1w3BKiDlDNbD6vM1kYLpeWCwwWPkob0LMWJ2gKJk=' 'sha256-VCul/cF2dFzd8xHSgv56T++LLkqGRYiggGEIUSq4DYU=' 'sha256-eDY0GdqziCJi7b7uuFZSZ44JBq7FeofxZNhLkwTa2CA='

This resulted in a few display issues on front end (on just a maintenance page) but the Wordpress admin area just couldn't function at all, so I didn't go any further.  The Inspect tool showed 99+ errors, so my thinking is that it is just impossible to whitelist all domains that need to load script, in a Wordpress website.
However, I don't know where to obtain further domains to white list (dynamic?) as the errors in the Inspect tool don't generally highlight the domain it was trying to retrieve a script form.
Thanks very much for your help.

An answer to your sub-question: is it silly to use 'unsafe-inline' if you have whitelisted domains: yes. But only yes if the rest  doesn’t include nonce-based directives. As soon as it does include nonce-based stuff, your 'unsafe-inline' only acts as a fallback for older browsers that do not know how to deal with nonces in CSP. Maybe your client anticipated that?

Thank you for your reply.  My two questions there: 1) even if nonce-based directives are specific, isn't having 'unsafe-inline' a fallback for older browsers whilst also allowing inline scripts in modern browsers?  2) while there is a (very time consuming) plugin (No unsafe inline) that can be used to create hashes and nonces in Wordpress, it is a rare plugin and not a highly tested approach; isn't a nonce-based (or hash) CSP generally something that does not work with Wordpress, as an approach?


No. When a modern browsers encounters nonce- they will consider this a directive and will disregard 'unsafe-inline'. 2. Not sure about wp plugins that can do the job. Generally, you should be able to program this yourself. Take the full output of wp and replace the script and style start-tags with one containing the nonce that you use in the headers or meta tag.



Thank you, that's really great info that I've not found anywhere else.  2. Yep, I've only seen one plugin that does (No unsafe-inline plugin).  As for creating this myself, I'll have to look at that...but my understanding is that wp has too many complexities to do so...and changes scripts with variables, so it would constantly require updating.



Firefox writes this to the console: "Content-Security-Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src: nonce-source or hash-source specified". (Make sure to have "Info"  enable.)



A rigorous approach is having a php as entry point that itself includes the root index.php. You'll need to route the incoming requests to your new file in htaccess, in the file set output buffering on, include the root index.php, read the output buffer and adjust all script and style tags to include a nonce that you will also send as csp headers when you echo the output.


Btw: the specs mention the 'unsafe-inline' behaviour here: 6.7.3.2. Does a source list allow all inline behavior for type?: "If expression matches the nonce-source or hash-source grammar, return "Does Not Allow"."
